# LinkedIn 'Jobs You May Be Interested In' Plugin adjust width and hight

Tags: html, iframe, linkedin-api

I am trying to add width on this this LinkedIn Plugin https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/jymbii because the plugin is too small, I tried adding `data-width=600` on the code but it is not working. Is there any way we can add width on this?

Answer (score 0):

You may just have forgotten the "" around 600

so the full thing would be:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/JYMBII" data-format="inline" data-width="600"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for that answer but this is what Im using, I added data-width but it's not working.

Comment: Try data-width="100%"  or data-width="200%" instead

Comment: still the same. it's using the default width.